# Ubuntu 16 sometimes gets stuck at boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I know that there are similar questions but I could not find what I have been looking for.

On ubuntu 16.04 everything was ok. Then one day the computer started to get stuck at the purple screen when I turned on the computer, but not every time. At the purple screen I hard reboot the computer and the grub menu comes and I choose Ubuntu (the first option) to boot normally and it boots normally. Every thing works fine from there on.

Then I shutdown the computer and turn it on again to see if the problem happens again, it just doesn't. But the next day, it gets stuck again.

The problem happens a few times a week. It is very annoying, I can not reproduce the problem when I want to.

So far, if the computer gets stuck, I can just hard reboot and then choose ubuntu from the grub menu and carry on normally. But if possible, I want to know what is wrong and fix the problem for good.

What might be the problem, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Notes:
I was using nvidia drivers and switched to nouveau but nothing seems to have changed.
Unfortunately I can't say at what point this weird problem started to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody ends up having this problem,

I (kind of) solved the problem by changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in the `/etc/default/grub` file from 0 to 5 which I must have set to 0 some time ago before the problem started.

Now each time I turn on the pc I see the grub menu but at least it doesn't get stuck.

Update: Upgrading to 20.04 solved the issue completely.